# Tkinter Entry Box Returning Value Zero Even When I Typed In Positive Numbers

Tags: python, datetime, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a program that lets users select a specific timeframe and displays relevant stock price plot. But right now even I have typed in some normal numbers, Python would only return this error message. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The second block of code is my buttons and entries. Ideally, after typing in starting and ending dates, once the submit button is clicked, the first block of code which is the show function should be triggered.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Casual Softwares\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in 
__call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "D:/Casual Softwares/python/untitled/UPDATING GRAPH.py", line 56, in 
show
start = dt.datetime(sY, sM, sD)
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Here is the relevant code

```
def show():
    global startD
    global startM
    global startY
    global endD
    global endM
    global endY
    global coy
    global firm
    sY=startY.get()
    sM=startM.get()
    sD=startD.get()
    eY=endY.get()
    eM=endM.get()
    eD=endD.get()

    if firm==False:
        popupmsg('Please Select A Company First')
    else:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (4, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
        ax1.clear()
        ax2.clear()
        start = dt.datetime(sY, sM, sD)
        end = dt.datetime(eY, eM, eD)
        df = web.get_data_yahoo(coy, start, end)
        ax1.plot(df.index, df['Adj Close'], label='Adjusted Close')
        ax2.bar(df.index, df['Volume'], label='Volume', width=25, color='c')
        for label in ax2.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(45)
        ax1.set_title(coy)
        ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3, ncol=2, 
borderaxespad=0)
        ax2.legend()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.show()
        canvas.draw()

def changePeriod():
    global startD
    global startM
    global startY
    global endD
    global endM
    global endY
    startD = IntVar()
    startM = IntVar()
    startY = IntVar()
    endD = IntVar()
    endM = IntVar()
    endY = IntVar()
    period = tk.Tk()
    period.wm_title('Periods')
    button1 = ttk.Button(period, text='Submit', width=10,command=show)
    button1.grid(row=5, columnspan=4, sticky='s')
    label = ttk.Label(period, text='Enter Dates',font=MID_FONT)
    label.grid(row=0,columnspan=4,sticky='n')
    label2=ttk.Label(period,text='Days')
    label3=ttk.Label(period,text='Months')
    label4=ttk.Label(period,text='Years')
    label5=ttk.Label(period,text='Start',font=MID_FONT)
    label2.grid(row=2,column=0)
    label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    label4.grid(row=4, column=0)
    label5.grid(row=1, column=0)

    entry1 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=startD,width=10)
    entry1.insert(0, 1)
    entry2 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=startM,width=10)
    entry2.insert(0, 1)
    entry3 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=startY,width=10)
    entry3.insert(0, 2010)
    entry1.grid(row=2,column=1)
    entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    entry1.focus_set()

    label6 = ttk.Label(period, text='Days')
    label7 = ttk.Label(period, text='Months')
    label8 = ttk.Label(period, text='Years')
    label9 = ttk.Label(period, text='End',font=MID_FONT)
    label6.grid(row=2, column=2)
    label7.grid(row=3, column=2)
    label8.grid(row=4, column=2)
    label9.grid(row=1, column=2)

    entry4 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=endD,width=10)
    entry4.insert(0, 20)
    entry5 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=endM,width=10)
    entry5.insert(0, 9)
    entry6 = ttk.Entry(period,textvariable=endY,width=10)
    entry6.insert(0, 2017)
    entry4.grid(row=2, column=3)
    entry5.grid(row=3, column=3)
    entry6.grid(row=4, column=3)

    period.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `entry1.insert(0, 1)` you are working around your `IntVar`s, so its value is never updated with the initial value. Instead, use `startD.set(1)`. Same for `startM`, `startY`, `endD`, `endM` and `endY`.

Comment: You are right I totally missed that! I'll delete my answer as yours is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you tobias_k